# Writing Data to Cassandra Hadoop Mapper(no reduce)

Tags: hadoop, cassandra

I get the following exception while trying to write to cassandra directly from the map, skipping the reduce task.

.
.
.

```
    ConfigHelper.setOutputColumnFamily(job.getConfiguration(), KEYSPACE, outputPath);

    job.setMapperClass(MapperToCassandra.class);
    job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);

    LOG.info("Writing output to Cassandra");
    //job.setReducerClass(ReducerToCassandra.class);
    job.setOutputFormatClass(ColumnFamilyOutputFormat.class);

    ConfigHelper.setRpcPort(job.getConfiguration(), "9160");
    //org.apache.cassandra.dht.LocalPartitioner
    ConfigHelper.setInitialAddress(job.getConfiguration(), "localhost");
    ConfigHelper.setPartitioner(job.getConfiguration(), "org.apache.cassandra.dht.RandomPartitioner");
```

.
.
.

Can anyone help me identify what I am missing?

```
12/05/17 16:01:38 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201205141442_0042_m_000000_0, Status : FAILED
java.io.IOException: InvalidRequestException(why:unconfigured columnfamily output)
    at org.apache.cassandra.hadoop.ColumnFamilyRecordWriter$RangeClient.run(ColumnFamilyRecordWriter.java:307)
Caused by: InvalidRequestException(why:unconfigured columnfamily output)
    at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$batch_mutate_result.read(Cassandra.java:19479)
    at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$Client.recv_batch_mutate(Cassandra.java:1035)
    at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$Client.batch_mutate(Cassandra.java:1009)
    at org.apache.cassandra.hadoop.ColumnFamilyRecordWriter$RangeClient.run(ColumnFamilyRecordWriter.java:299)
```

Answer (score 1):

Fortunately, I could resolve this myself.

InvalidRequestException(why:unconfigured columnfamily output)

This Exception is encountered if the given column family name is not created in the database.

The column family means table in relational database. There are two ways to solve this problem.
In java code, you can change the name of the column family to the one existing in the database.